# What is the issue due to which debian hangs at fsck /dev/sda? What is the solution?

Tags: debian, boot, grub, fsck

What is the issue due to which debian hangs at fsck /dev/sda? What is the solution?

This is the screenshot of Debian in normal mode:

[image]

This is the screenshot of Debian in recovery mode:

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting screenshots, post in text. And give more details. What happens, exactly? Does it complete the fsck, or just hang?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm using mobile to post this question and posting text would be too much typing, especially when the screenshot and typing needs to be done on the mobile itself.

The booting process hangs at the screenshots shown. I don't think it completes the fsck at all, but it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Um, then maybe wait till you can use a proper computer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't wait. Nor can I get a proper computer anytime soon, other than the one I'm facing this issue on and my mobile phone.

Comment: Ok, please give us a little context/information about this system. It is a new installation or not? If not, how long have you been using it? If it is a new installation, did you complete installing it? In any case, is reinstallation an option?

Comment: This is a Debian Wheezy system I've been using since almost 3 years now. Reinstallation could be the last option, provided I don't have to lose data on other partitions.

This is a dual boot system with Debian Wheezy and Win 7 and Windows boots well, without any problems. Right now, I'm using a Windows built-in utility called Windows Memory Diagnostics Tool to check for memory issues, if any.

Debian has been my default OS and I work primarily on it and so it also contains bulk of my work and software of interest.

Comment: This is either a filesystem corruption issue, or there a hardware problem with the hard disks. There might be other possibilities, but those are by far the most likely. I don't think ext4 is that inclined to get corrupt, so hard disk problems are more likely. Can you run a disk checking utility on your hard disk? That would help to clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

instead of choosing automatic recovery, select an emergency shell, then try:

```
$ e2fsck -fy /dev/sda1
$ e2fsck -fy /dev/sda3
$ e2fsck -fy /dev/sda7
```

This will check the filesystems, option -f forces the checking to continue even if the filesystem seems clean and option -y forces a 'yes' answer to any interactive questions. If you are happy to sit and watch for what could be a long time, you can try without the 'y'.

You could also try option -c for a much more thorough read-only test of the disk surface, or even -cc for a read-write non-destructive test, but these will be much slower, and only to be tried if the faster options don't bring success.

If you can't boot successfully, download the SystemRescueCD and prepare this either as CD or as USB and boot to it, then do the same (i.e. above) from the command line.

Comment: I tried booting using the emergency option in Grub but the boot process still hangs at the same level of mounting sda7 ext4-fs. Here is the screenshot:



I'm at the end of my wits. Please help me through this. I'll be very grateful!

This is the screenshot of Debian in recovery mode:


http://imgur.com/Y72MEXQ

Comment: @muglikar I have added a suggestion to use SystemRescueCD

Comment: As soon as the windows memory checking is done, I'll go for this option.

Btw, I think someone (who also uses my system) has just told me that they did something like change the ownership of some directories inside or the entire /etc/ directory to a non-root user while installing some utility.

Has this change caused this tricky situation?

Comment: @muglikar No, something as trivial as filesystem permissions would not cause the kind of behavior you are seeing. If someone else used your system, talk to them if they have any idea what might have gone wrong. Did they turn off the computer without shutting down properly, for example? That could cause filesystem corruption.

Comment: Well, that happens all the time - Laptop not being turned off properly as the battery is dying and electricity often goes off in this part of the world.